# An alternate to impress.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, impress.js

I am looking for an alternate tool like impress.js for online presentations. Can someone suggest me any which is cross browser compatible??

impress.js is a great tool but not supported in older versions of Firefox and chrome and IE. I have tried [deck.js](http://imakewebthings.com/deck.js) as well but transitions for this too only supported in modern browsers. i am looking for something which works in older browser too.

Any help is appreciated . Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: You know, there's a reason why the transitions won't work in older browsers...

Answer (score 4):

Flash ? lol
what these frameworks are using (CSS3 i suspect) dont work on older browsers , so you are not going to find a library that does the same things and work in IE6-8.